# Why is my method returning in the middle?

Tags: java, android

The following method is only executing half-way:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location newLocation) {
    double lat = newLocation.getLatitude();
    double lon = newLocation.getLongitude();
    boolean firstGoodFix = (waitingForLoc && newLocation.getAccuracy() < 30); // <= EXECUTION STOPS AFTER THIS LINE
    if (currentLocation == null || firstGoodFix) {
        LatLng myLocation = new LatLng(lat, lon);
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myLocation));
    }
    currentLocation = newLocation;
    if (firstGoodFix) {
        sendMyLocation(newLocation);
        waitingForLoc = false;
    } else {
        sendMyLocation();
    }
}
```

When I step through the code, it executes normally up until the indicated line and then jumps to the closing brace and the rest of the code never executes.

`newLocation` is valid, and so is `waitingForLoc` (true).  `newLocation.getAccuracy()` should be returning around `1000`.  `currentLocation` is null.  `firstGoodFix` does not appear in the list of variables at the end of the method which leads me to believe that line is not completing.

What's going on here?

**EDIT**

Following the suggestions below, I've changed the structure of the method somewhat and discovered that no matter what I did, whenever the value of `waitingForLoc` was read, the method would stop executing.  The only thing that will make it work is removing the variable entirely.

I also tried setting `waitingForLoc` = true as the first line of the method to ensure it had a value, which made no difference.  Previously it was being set in `onResume()`.

So my question now becomes: why does reading this variable cause execution to stop?  There doesn't seem to be any relevant output in `LogCat`.

Comment: are you sure the deployed code is current? Other than that, only an exception could terminate the method there.

Comment: can you try running after doing project clean?

Comment: I did do a project clean, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I have no experience in Android but the behaviour you describe seems a lot like trying to debug an optimized application (i.e. a `release` version). After such compiler optimizations, trying to trace such an application surely produces a crazy path through the source code. Perhaps Android has a similar concept that might apply in your case?

Comment: I'm not really sure how I would even generate an optimized version.  I didn't build the application any differently than I have in the past.

Answer (score 0):

You have a method there. Split the parts that make up your firstGoodFix boolean into separate booleans, then re-operate into firstGoodFix to see if that method is coming back with something that couldn't possible be less than (or bigger than or equal) 30 (like a NAN or an error, God knows :)

Answer (score 0):

May be it is because

```
(waitingForLoc && newLocation.getAccuracy() < 30);
```

This will come like `(true && 1000 < 30)`. I think the compiler try to get the output of `true && 1000` at first. That is why the method stops executing at middle. Try to change that line to `(waitingForLoc && (newLocation.getAccuracy() < 30));` like this. And let me know what happens. I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Since newLocation.getAccuracy() is returning around 1000 and waitingForLoc is a boolean variable , try changing your code to:

```
//Store value of function in a local variable
boolean getAccuracyValue = false;
if(newLocation.getAccuracy() < 30)
{
  getAccuracyValue=true;
}

//Now set the firstGoodFix

boolean firstGoodFix=(waitingForLoc && getAccuracyValue);
```

Ideally your solution should work. But I am assuming the problem is because of the function. I do not know why.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use brackets in your line, like this:

```
boolean firstGoodFix = (waitingForLoc && (newLocation.getAccuracy() < 30) );
```

Notice the extra brackets in your comparison.

PS: To those voting down my answer, would you care to comment and explain why are you voting down? I was just trying to help, and this way you just discourage people to help other people...